# Select row from a DataFrame based on the type of the object(i.e. str)

Tags: python, pandas

So there's a DataFrame say:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...                 'A':[1,2,'Three',4],
...                 'B':[1,'Two',3,4]})
>>> df
       A    B
0      1    1
1      2  Two
2  Three    3
3      4    4
```

I want to select the rows whose datatype of particular row of a particular column is of type `str`.

For example I want to select the row where `type` of data in the column `A` is a `str`.
 so it should print something like:

```
   A      B
2  Three  3
```

Whose intuitive code would be like:

```
df[type(df.A) == str]
```

Which obviously doesn't works!

Thanks please help!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This works:

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Comment: Don't use `type(obj) == typeobj`, ever. Use `isinstance(obj, typeobj)`, or if subclasses must be excluded, `type(obj) is typeobj` (identity testing, not equality).

Answer (score 11):

You can do something *similar* to what you're asking with

```
In [14]: df[pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').isnull()]
Out[14]: 
       A  B
2  Three  3
```

Why only similar? Because Pandas stores things in homogeneous columns (all entries in a column are of the same type). Even though you constructed the DataFrame from heterogeneous types, they are all made into columns each of the lowest common denominator:

```
In [16]: df.A.dtype
Out[16]: dtype('O')
```

Consequently, you can't ask which rows are of what type - they will all be of the same type. What you *can* do is to try to convert the entries to numbers, and check where the conversion failed (this is what the code above does).

Comment: Thanks:) but what's with `isnull()` ? what does it return  ?

Comment: @wolframalpha Given a Series, it returns a boolean series indicating which entries of the series had null values in them. So, first we use `to_numeric` (which places a null value when the conversion failed), then run `isnull` on the result.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer since even if there is one string the whole column would be a string. The concoction is too simple of a scenario hence the accepted answer worked. In real life situations this is a live saver.

Comment: this is the best and fastest solution (far better than applying a lambda); should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's generally a bad idea to use a series to hold mixed numeric and non-numeric types. This will cause your series to have dtype `object`, which is nothing more than a sequence of pointers. Much like `list` and, indeed, many operations on such series can be more efficiently processed with `list`.

With this disclaimer, you can use Boolean indexing via a list comprehension:

```
res = df[[isinstance(value, str) for value in df['A']]]

print(res)

       A  B
2  Three  3
```

The equivalent is possible with `pd.Series.apply`, but this is no more than a thinly veiled loop and may be slower than the list comprehension:

```
res = df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

If you are certain all non-numeric values must be strings, then you can convert to numeric and look for nulls, i.e. values that cannot be converted:

```
res = df[pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
```