# Taking logarithm of column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Im quite new to programming (in python) and I would like to create a new variable that is the logarithm of a column (from an imported excel file). I have tried different solutions from this site, but I keep getting an error. My latest error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'log'.` 
I have already dropped all the values that are not "numbers', but I still don't know how to convert the values from strings to integers (if this is the case, because 'int(neighborhood)' doesn't work).

This is the code I have now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel("kwb-2016_del_col_del_row.xls")
df = df[df.m_woz != "."] # drop rows with values "."
neighborhood=df[df.recs=="Neighborhood"]
neighborhood=neighborhood["m_woz"]
print(neighborhood)

np.log(neighborhood)
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-46698de51811> in <module>()
     12 print(neighborhood)
     13 
---> 14 np.log(neighborhood)


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'log'
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: But the way to solve it is two lines below that in comment  `y=np.log(buurt["g_woz"])`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That line gives an error as well (key error). If I remove the key from that line, I get the same error as I described above

Comment: Then the column has another name than `g_woz`. Please do not just throw away parts that error, this is usually not a good way to debug code.

Comment: I didn't know what to do with that error because I'm fairly sure that that is the name of the column

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can't copy the whole error, but this is the beginning of the error:
'TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)'

Comment: Please reset your kernel, it seems you've assigned `np` to something else along the way.

Comment: What is the relationship between `buurt` and `neighborhood`?  Also, it's a good idea to use `.loc` when indexing.

Comment: Excuse me, I changed it to English for this site, but I unfortunately forgot to change it in the error. Sorry for that. In the error buurt=neighborhood

Comment: @Kate It seems you've glossed over my comment. Did you restart the kernel or not?

Comment: @Kate: please [edit] your question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, I did. twice, but still the same error

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem to what should I edit it?

Comment: @Kate Do this... `del np; import numpy as np`

Comment: Aaaaand, did it work?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Did this, and I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are not removing the data you think you are?
Try printing the data types to see what they are.
In a DataFrame, your column might be filled with **objects** instead of numbers.

`print(df.dtypes)`

Also, you might want to look at these two pages

[Select row from a DataFrame based on the type of the object(i.e. str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275533/select-row-from-a-dataframe-based-on-the-type-of-the-objecti-e-str)

[Pandas: convert dtype 'object' to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int)

Here's an example I constructed and ran interactively that correctly gets the logarithms (don't type >>>):

```
>>> raw_data = {'m_woz': ['abc', 'def', 1.23, 45.6, '.xyz'], 
    'recs': ['Neighborhood', 'Neighborhood', 
    'unknown', 'Neighborhood', 'whatever']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['m_woz', 'recs'])
>>> print(df.dtypes)
m_woz    object
recs     object
dtype: object
```

Note that the type is object, not `float` or `int` or `str`

Continuing on, here is what `df` and `neighborhood` look like:

```
>>> df
  m_woz          recs
0    42  Neighborhood
1   def  Neighborhood
2  1.23       unknown
3  45.6  Neighborhood
4  .xyz      whatever

>>> neighborhood=df[df.recs=="Neighborhood"]
>>> neighborhood

  m_woz          recs
0    42  Neighborhood
1   def  Neighborhood
3  45.6  Neighborhood
```

And here are the tricks...
This line selects all rows in `neighborhood` that are `int` or `float` (be careful to fix indents if you copy/paste this

```
>>> df_num_strings = neighborhood[neighborhood['m_woz'].
        apply(lambda x: type(x) in (int, float))]

>>> df_num_strings
  m_woz          recs
0    42  Neighborhood
3  45.6  Neighborhood
```

Almost there... convert the numbers to floating point from string

```
>>> df_float = df_num_strings['m_woz'].astype(str).astype(float)
>>> df_float
0    42.0
3    45.6
```

Finally, compute logarithms:

```
>>> np.log(df_float)
0    3.737670
3    3.819908
Name: m_woz, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This worked! Except the part of the apply function, as all the values were not seen as floats or integers, but the 'astype' functions worked. I don't know why, but I have tried that one before and it didn't work then. Maybe I changed the code after I tried it. Thanks so much for your effort @coldspeed, WillemVanOnsem and of course akubot!

Comment: @Kate great news, please mark the answer as correct if you don't mind