# Select rows from Pandas dataframe where a specific column contains numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where a column (column B) can contain a letters, a number or nothing at all. Lets say the data frame is:

```
A   B    C
1   2    Dog
3   C    Bird
30  nan  Cat
11  4.1  Wolf
```

And I want to get rows conditionally, based on whether there is a number in column B:

```
A   B    C
1   2    Dog
11  4.1  Wolf
```

I have found that I can limit the dataframe to only rows that contain values by entering `df.loc[df["B"].notnull()]`. What I'm trying to find out is whether or not there is an equivalent version of `.notnull()` that can select only rows where column B contains a number?

Comment: Post a sample dataframe and expected outputs.

Comment: try doing: `df.loc[df["B"].str.contains("\d+")]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select row from a DataFrame based on the type of the object(i.e. str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275533/select-row-from-a-dataframe-based-on-the-type-of-the-objecti-e-str)

Comment: Added an example data frame to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

To find integers and decimal numbers, define a function that will take a string as an input, attempt to convert a value to a floating point number (which will succeed if you have an integer or a floating point number), and will handle possible errors: a `ValueError` is raised if you pass it a string that can't be converted to a floating point number, and a `TypeError` is raised if a null value is passed to `float()`, so handle these two exceptions:

```
def safe_float_convert(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True # numeric, success!
    except ValueError:
        return False # not numeric
    except TypeError:
        return False # null type
```

Now use `map()` to map the new function to column B of the dataframe, element-wise, and create a boolean mask:

```
mask = df['B'].map(safe_float_convert)
```

and use the `.loc[]` function, passing in the boolean mask:

```
numeric_df = df.loc[mask]
```